# Using ternary operator inside select option tag

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, conditional-operator

Currently I have a select box that is filling in its data from the controller class. As of now all the values are filling in properly as intended, but there are some null values for `firstname` for which I'm trying to add a ternary operator to replace it with email.

This doesn't seem to work in my controller class as I'm placing the parentheses wrong.

Here's my current code:

```
public function getContacts($id){
    $option = "<option value='0'>Select</option>";

    $modelList = $this->listings_model->get_contact(array('contact_type'=>3),'firstname,lastname,email,refno');  
    foreach($modelList as $m){
        $option .= "<option value='".$m['firstname']." ".$m['lastname']." - ".$m['refno']."' id='".$m['id']."'>".$m['firstname']." ".$m['lastname']." - ".$m['refno']."</option>";
    }

    echo json_encode($option);
}
```

I've tried the following but I'm getting a syntax error:

```
$option .= "<option value='"($m['firstname'].$m['lastname'] ? $m['firstname']." ".$m['lastname']." - ".$m['refno'] : $m['email'])"' id='".$m['id']."'>".$m['firstname']." ".$m['lastname']." - ".$m['refno']."</option>";
```

What I want to achieve is this:

`value="<?php echo ($ow['firstname'].$ow['lastname']?$ow['firstname'].' '.$ow['lastname']:($ow['email']?$ow['email']:$ow['mobile'])).' - '.$ow['refno']; ?>"`

Comment: ``$m['firstname'].$m['lastname']`` is the evil. You should be checking for null value for only ``$m['firstname']`` instead of both.

Comment: and it should be ``$option .= "<option value='".($m['firstname'] ? $m['firstname']." ".$m['lastname']." - ".$m['refno'] : $m['email'])."' id='".$m['id']."'>".$m['firstname']." ".$m['lastname']." - ".$m['refno']."</option>";``

Comment: @OMiShah okay but now what if I want to check by firstname and lastname. I actually want it to look like this: `($ow['firstname'].$ow['lastname']?$ow['firstname'].' '.$ow['lastname']:($ow['email']?$ow['email']:$ow['mobile'])).' - '.$ow['refno'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have these things called variable that help code become readable. Also, parentheses can help identify groups of variables with operations between them in a ternary operator. You have several misplaced `'` and `"` in your code, both in PHP and in HTML.

From what I understand from your requirements the following code does this:
if firstname and lastname are not empty it will use `<firstname> <lastname> - <ref>` for the value and text of the option else it will use `<email>` if email is not empty else `<mobile>`

```
$name = ( $m['firstname'] && $m['lastname'] ) ? ( $m['firstname'] . ' ' . $m['lastname'] ) : ( '' );
$value = $name ? ($name . ' - ' . $m['refno']) : ($m['email'] ? $m['email'] : $m['mobile']);
$id = $m['id'];
$option .= "<option value=\"$value\" id=\"$id\">$value</option>";
```

By the way, you cannot json_encode an HTML string.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is this basically `($ow['firstname'].$ow['lastname']?$ow['firstname'].' '.$ow['lastname']:($ow['email']?$ow['email']:$ow['mobile'])).' - '.$ow['refno'];` where it'll check if firstname lastname is there then place those values else place email or mobile. So now how can I form this in $value variable?

Comment: @JAYZ do you want to check if both firstname and lastname are empty or one of them is enough?

Comment: I need both of them and then further there should be a ternary operator in email as well as I've shown in my example above

Comment: @JAYZ updated the answer for those requirements, and please do note that the json_encode at the bottom is certainly not in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

`$m['firstname'].$m['lastname']` is the evil. You should be checking for `null` value for only `$m['firstname']` instead of the both.

Also, it should be:

```
$option .= "<option value='".($m['firstname'] !== null ? $m['firstname']." ".$m['lastname']." - ".$m['refno'] : $m['email'])."' id='".$m['id']."'>".($m['firstname'] !== null ? $m['firstname']." ".$m['lastname']." - ".$m['refno'] : $m['email'])."</option>";
```